# Difference between ./usr and /usr when running a command

Tags: linux, centos7

I have two directories in my new CentOS7:

1. *`Work_Folder1/my_project/linux_dev.cfg`*
2. *`Work_Folder2/my_project/linux_dev.cfg`*

If I try to run the command `./usr/bin/buildout -c linux_dev.cfg` the build works fine from dir (1). If I try the same from (2) it says the `./usr/bin/buildout not exists`.

After trying I see that from (2), `/usr/bin/buildout -c linux_dev.cfg` command works. So whats the role of `.` in here?

Comment: Please state the output of `pwd`.

Answer (score 0):

The command ./usr/bin/buildout looks for usr folder in the current directory.. While /usr/bin/buildout looks for usr in the root folder.. You might have usr folder in root as well as Work_Folder1, but not in WorkFolder2

Answer (score -1):

The `.` indicates that you want to start looking for the `buildout` executable in the directory you are currently in. So for `./usr/bin/buildout`, we are looking for a `usr` directory under the current directory, a `bin` directory under that, and a `buildout` executable under that.

Without the dot (i.e. `/usr/bin/buildout`), we begin looking in the root of the filesystem (i.e. `/`) for a `usr` directory, and then `bin` and `buildout`.

I'll bet if you look in your `Work_Folder1/my_project/linux_dev.cfg` directory, you'll find a `usr` directory. If you look in `Work_Folder2/my_project/linux_dev.cfg`, you won't.